# Нанесение объектов на карту из geoJSON

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно нанести много объектов на карту из файла geoJSON. С точками (Point) проблем нет, а вот LineString и MultiPolygon рисоваться не  хотят. Объектов много, поэтому использую ObjectManager.
Повторил пример из песочницы https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Нарисовались только точки. Распарсил файл по типам. Опять рисуются только точки. 
В файле нет объектов с типом Polygon. Есть только Point, LineString и MultiPolygon.

Answer (score 0):

OM не умеет рисовать MultiPolygon, MultiLinestring, MultiPoint. Но можно преобразовать их к обычным Polygon, Linestring, Point и тогда он начнёт их отображать.

Comment: Преобразовать - это изменить type="Polygon"?

Comment: и должно выглядеть как то так: objectManager.add(geoJSON_Polygon); map.geoObjects.add(objectManager); И все? А как задать цвет, толщину линий, прозрачность, заливку? Если не трудно, можно примерчик?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что ОМ Polygon и Linestring рисует. Просто их не видно. Для Point пропсаны свойства objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#yellowCircleDotIcon');
                    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');

Comment: Преобразовать - это не только изменить type на polygon или linestring, но и преобразовать данные. MultiPolygon, MultiLinestring - это просто несколько полигонов и линий внутри одного объекта. По второму вопросу: Вот тут показано https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_spatial как можно задавать внешний вид.

Comment: "Я подозреваю, что ОМ Polygon и Linestring рисует. Просто их не видно." Соберите пример с вашими данными так: https://jsfiddle.net/86zsbmud/